# container height doesnt extent auto

Tags: css

Container doesn't extend when I add a `div` into container `div`. I mean when I add a `div` to container, `div` overflow the container `div`.
Thanks for your helping.

**main.css**:

```
body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    margin:0px;
    background:repeat-x url(resimler/Bg.jpg) #57513e;
}
.Container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:white;
    **height:auto;
    ** overflow:hidden
}
.UstAlan {
    margin:auto;
    background-image:url(resimler/ConteinerUstBg.jpg);
    height:21px;
}
.Slider {
    margin:auto;
    height:280px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
    width:960px;
}
.TestAlan {
    margin:auto;
    width:960px;
    background:black;
    float:left
}
.BirTest {
    width:940px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin-top:10px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    height:auto
}
.Sol {
    height:auto;
    width:450px;
    background:#d7e9ba;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.Sag {
    height:auto;
    width:450px;
    background:yellow;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.Baslik {
    background:url(resimler/KutucukUst.jpg);
    height:24px;
    width:450px;
}
```

Comment: why star star hieght. **height:auto;**

Comment: Try this   .Container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:white;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

May be because you use float:right; float:left;

show your html also..